# Grails access current environment from within config.groovy

Tags: grails, configuration

Using the Grails OAuth plugin requires that an absolute callback URL be provided in Config.groovy.  However I have different serverURLs for each environment.

Is there a way to get the current environment from inside Config.groovy, here's an example of what I want to do:

```
def devServerUrl = 'http://dev.example.com'
def prodServerUrl = 'http://prod.example.com'
def currentServerUrl = grailsApplication.metadata.environment == 'development' ? devServerUrl : prodServerUrl;

environments {
    development {
        grails {
            serverURL = devServerUrl
        }
    }
    production {
        grails {
            serverURL = prodServerUrl
        }
    }
}

oauth {
    providers {
        runkeeper {
            api = RunKeeperApi
            key = 'key'
            secret = 'secret'
            callback = currentServerUrl + '/oauth/runkeeper/callback'
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I think that Environment.current works in Config.groovy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
def currentServerUrl = Environment.current.name == 'development' ? devServerUrl : prodServerUrl;
```

Comment: Worked beautifully, thanks!  I also had to import grails.util.Environment at the top of Config.groovy.

Comment: Or use the built-in constants: Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT

Answer (score 0):

I think it is cleaner to set different `grails.serverURL` for each environment and then do:

```
callback = "${grails.serverURL}/oauth/runkeeper/callback"
```